# iOS SwiftUI: NavigationLink in macOS simulator does not work

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

### The Problem:

The **NavigationLinks** in the **macOS** version of the SwiftUI app don't work properly.

In my case is a **MasterDetailNavigationView**.

### What I've tried

- I have the problem running the app with the macOS simulator, and also running the archived application.
- I still have the problem with a brand new project with the sample code below:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("View One")) {
                    Text("ONE")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("View Two")) {
                    Text("TWO")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

### How to reproduce the problem:

Copy and paste the above code in a new SwiftUI project. Enable the macOS tick the the target settings. And the run on the macOS emulator.

### Versions:

macOS: 10.15.4 (19E266)

Xcode: 11.4 (11E146)

Comment: I've tried the code, using Xcode 11.4 running on macos catalina 10.15.4 (catalyst) and all works well for me.

Comment: Same here, the initial window was too small, so I just resized but I was able to see the switch between the views just fine

Comment: you can also try adding .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())

Comment: did you keep switching between the views?

Comment: yes, no problems. I'm not quite sure what you mean by macos emulator.

Comment: I noticed that Text("Hello, World!") should be after the Spacer().

Comment: correction. I'm having problems now, if I don't include .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())

Comment: that's the point using the app in the macOS simulator with a master detail